# How to correctly implement a batch-input LSTM network in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

This [release](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.1.10) of PyTorch seems provide the `PackedSequence` for variable lengths of input for recurrent neural network. However, I found it's a bit hard to use it correctly.

Using `pad_packed_sequence` to recover an output of a RNN layer which were fed by `pack_padded_sequence`, we got a `T x B x N` tensor `outputs` where `T` is the max time steps, `B` is the batch size and `N` is the hidden size. I found that for short sequences in the batch, the subsequent output will be all zeros.

Here are my questions.

1. For a single output task where the one would need the last output of all the sequences, simple `outputs[-1]` will give a wrong result since this tensor contains lots of zeros for short sequences. One will need to construct indices by sequence lengths to fetch the individual last output for all the sequences. Is there more simple way to do that?
2. For a multiple output task (e.g. seq2seq), usually one will add a linear layer `N x O` and reshape the batch outputs `T x B x O` into `TB x O` and compute the cross entropy loss with the true targets `TB` (usually integers in language model). In this situation, do these zeros in batch output matters?

Answer (score 14):

**Question 1 - Last Timestep**

This is the code that i use to get the output of the last timestep. I don't know if there is a simpler solution. If it is, i'd like to know it. I followed this [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-multiple-packedsequence-input-ordering/2106/3) and grabbed the relative code snippet for my `last_timestep` method. This is my forward.

```
class BaselineRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def last_timestep(self, unpacked, lengths):
        # Index of the last output for each sequence.
        idx = (lengths - 1).view(-1, 1).expand(unpacked.size(0),
                                               unpacked.size(2)).unsqueeze(1)
        return unpacked.gather(1, idx).squeeze()

    def forward(self, x, lengths):
        embs = self.embedding(x)

        # pack the batch
        packed = pack_padded_sequence(embs, list(lengths.data),
                                      batch_first=True)

        out_packed, (h, c) = self.rnn(packed)

        out_unpacked, _ = pad_packed_sequence(out_packed, batch_first=True)

        # get the outputs from the last *non-masked* timestep for each sentence
        last_outputs = self.last_timestep(out_unpacked, lengths)

        # project to the classes using a linear layer
        logits = self.linear(last_outputs)

        return logits
```

**Question 2 - Masked Cross Entropy Loss**

Yes, by default the zero padded timesteps (targets) matter. However, it is very easy to mask them. You have two options, depending on the version of PyTorch that you use.

1. PyTorch [0.2.0](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.2.0): Now pytorch supports masking directly in the [CrossEntropyLoss](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), with the `ignore_index` argument. For example, in language modeling or seq2seq, where i add zero padding,  i mask the zero padded words (target) simply like this:

   loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
2. PyTorch [0.1.12](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.1.12) and older: In the older versions of PyTorch, masking was not supported, so you had to implement your own workaround. I solution that i used, was [masked_cross_entropy.py](https://gist.github.com/jihunchoi/f1434a77df9db1bb337417854b398df1), by [jihunchoi](https://github.com/jihunchoi). You may be also interested in this [discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/563).

Comment: I am trying your solution, and I got the error:
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/skip-thoughts.torch/pytorch/tmpRNN.py", line 13, in last_timestep
    return unpacked.gather(1, idx).squeeze()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py", line 684, in gather
    return Gather.apply(self, dim, index)
RuntimeError: save_for_backward can only save input or output tensors, but argument 0 doesn't satisfy this condition

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago, I found [this method](https://gist.github.com/ritchie46/a6d09965fc4d81047f1b0c52ebb35cdc#file-rnn_minibatch-py-L54) which uses indexing to accomplish the same task with a one-liner.

I have my dataset batch first (`[batch size, sequence length, features]`), so for me:

```
unpacked_out = unpacked_out[np.arange(unpacked_out.shape[0]), lengths - 1, :]
```

where `unpacked_out` is the output of `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence`.

I have compared it with the method [described here](https://blog.nelsonliu.me/2018/01/24/extracting-last-timestep-outputs-from-pytorch-rnns/), which looks similar to the `last_timestep()` method Christos Baziotis is using above (also recommended [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-get-the-output-at-the-last-timestep-for-batched-sequences/12057/4)), and the results are the same in my case.